# Combining two functions together

Tags: php

I have two functions `nl2br` and `substr` which I would like to combine together, could someone please tell how I would achieve this:

```
<?php echo nl2br($row_rsMyrecordSet['text']); ?>

<?php echo substr($row_rsMyrecordSet['text'],0,10); ?>
```

I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
<?php echo nl2br & substr($row_rsMyrecordSet['text'],0,10); ?>
```

Comment: sidenote: it needs 2x `&&` to be syntatically correct.

Comment: `<?php echo nl2br(substr($row_rsMyrecordSet['text'],0,10)); ?>` give that a go. Might work. Or `<?php echo nl2br(substr($row_rsMyrecordSet['text']),0,10); ?>`

Comment: Might, crazier things have happened

Comment: *"Many thanks Tony"* - Frank Smith? err.. ok Are you being "frank" about Tony?

Comment: I'll have what he's having bartender - @Dagon

Comment: Using `&&` is for condtional statements.

Comment: wasent a bad first guess i have seen stupider ideas

Comment: @Dagon I did make a slight edit to my *Might work* bit. Added a second example. Not entirely sure but it's worth a shot. Maybe OP'll say "Make that an answer". who knows. Or, somebody's gonna come and pull the rug from under my feet.

Comment: heys it's JS: `echo nl2br.substr($row_rsMyrecordSet['text']),0,10);`

Comment: So Frank Tony, did `<?php echo nl2br(substr($row_rsMyrecordSet['text'],0,10)); ?>` or `<?php echo nl2br(substr($row_rsMyrecordSet['text']),0,10); ?>` work? I've got a train to catch. I have to get to @Dagon's place before he drinks all of that cherry wine ;-)

Comment: Tony here using Dads (Frank) account - oops...

Comment: And the winner is...

Comment: <?php echo nl2br(substr($row_rsMyrecordSet['text'],0,10)); ?> - worked like a charm, thanks so much

Comment: You're welcome Tony. I posted it as an answer, if you choose to accept it to close the question and it be marked as solved. *Cheers* - Now let's see if @Dagon hasn't eaten all of those corn chips ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing my first post was indeed the answer to this problem, am posting it as an answer.

You can actually use both functions, just as long as they're wrapped in brackets.

*Like so...*

```
<?php echo nl2br(substr($row_rsMyrecordSet['text'],0,10)); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use any predefined function with other predefined

```
<?php echo nl2br(substr($row_rsMyrecordSet['text'],0,10)); ?>
```

Comment: This is the second answer I noticed you placed underneath mine. The other being http://stackoverflow.com/a/31018578/, coincidence? I kind of doubt it. That isn't my downvote, but you probably got it because of it.