# Execute Success but num_rows return 0 [PHP-MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The problem I just got is,

the `$update_stmt->execute()` is ok, and **data in database already update**

but, `$update_resultrow = $update_stmt->num_rows;` **return 0 ?**

I tried to copy MySQL command to run in query and it also worked well, like this:

```
UPDATE ACCOUNT_EMPLOYEE SET NAME = 'cccccc' WHERE ID = 1
```

---

Problem's Code here:

```
$update_sql = "UPDATE ACCOUNT_EMPLOYEE SET NAME = ? WHERE ID = ?";
if ($update_stmt = $conn -> prepare($update_sql)) {
    if ($update_stmt->bind_param("si",
        $newname,
        $acc_id
    )
    ) {
        if ($update_stmt->execute()) {
            // must declare here to be able to get num_rows
            $update_stmt->store_result();
            $update_resultrow = $update_stmt->num_rows;
            if ($update_resultrow == 0) {
                echo $error_forgot_noresult . '????' . $acc_id ;
                $update_stmt->close();
                $conn->close();
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: replace `$update_stmt->num_rows;` with `$update_stmt->rowCount()`

Comment: @Umair that's PDO, OP is using mysqli_

Comment: so it should be `$update_stmt->num_rows();`

Comment: `$update_resultrow = $update_stmt->num_rows;` what are you trying to achieve here, if the execute was successful? if so, you need to use `affected_rows`, or read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php i.e.: from the manual `$rows = $query->num_rows;` - and for affected_rows http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: Yes, Fred -ii-, I never noticed that it has ->affected_rows. please post as answer, and I will marked it here

Comment: @SruitA.Suk It has been done, *cheers*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Yes, Fred -ii-, I never noticed that it has ->affected_rows. please post as answer, and I will marked it here*

As per OP's request.

Seeing that the goal here is to test if the query was indeed successful, you need to use `affected_rows`.

As per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

> printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);

- Object oriented style

> int $mysqli->affected_rows;

---

Sidenote:

Using

```
$update_resultrow = $update_stmt->num_rows;
```

and checking for errors, would have thrown an error, rather than "return 0".

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the number of rows affected by your query instead of finding number of rows as below:

```
$update_sql = "UPDATE ACCOUNT_EMPLOYEE SET NAME = ? WHERE ID = ?";
if ($update_stmt = $conn -> prepare($update_sql)) {
    if ($update_stmt->bind_param("si",
        $newname,
        $acc_id
    )
    ) {
        if ($update_stmt->execute()) {
            // must declare here to be able to get num_rows
            $update_stmt->store_result();
            $update_resultrow = $update_stmt->affected_rows;
            if ($update_resultrow == 0) {
                echo $error_forgot_noresult . '????' . $acc_id ;
                $update_stmt->close();
                $conn->close();
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```